# What is the Android equivalent of iOS's XArbitraryZVertical

Tags: android, ios, android-sensors, sensormanager, cmmotionmanager

In iOS, when setting up the motion sensors, a developer can pass in an initialization setting (XArbitraryZVertical) that, essentially, zeros out all of the data from the sensors in it's current position.  I am wonder if there is an Android equivalent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR provides this functionality.